# Find the operator norm of $T$ where $T:C[a,b]\to C[c,d]$ is defined by $T(f)(t)=\int_a^bk(s,t)f(s)\ ds$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $k(s,t)$, where $(s,t)\in [a,b]\times[c,d]$ be continuous. Consider the integral operator $T:C[a,b]\to C[c,d]$ defined by $T(f)(t)=\int_a^bk(s,t)f(s)\ ds$.

Now $|T(f)(t)|\leq \int_a^b|k(s,t)f(s)|\ ds\leq \int_a^b|k(s,t)||f(s)|\ ds\leq (b-a)\|k\|_\infty\|f\|_\infty$ for all $ f\in C[a,b]$. Therefore $\|T\|\leq \|k\|_\infty(b-a)$, where $\|T\|$ is the operator norm of $T$ defined by $$\|T\|=\inf\{M:\|T(f)\|\leq M\|f\|\ \forall f\in C[a,b] \}.$$ My question is can we find what exactly $\|T\|$ is? Or does it depend on $k$? A hint will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Putting specific $f$'s give you bounds of the norm from below. See if you can find a sequence of $f$'s in which those bounds tend to the upper bound you found.